# How do I make this Query against EF Efficient?

Tags: entity-framework

Using EF4.  Assume I have this:

```
IQueryable<ParentEntity> qry = myRepository.GetParentEntities();  
Int32 n = 1;
```

What I want to do is this, but EF can't compare against null.

```
qry.Where( parent => parent.Children.Where( child => child.IntCol == n ) != null )
```

What works is this, but the SQL it produces (as you would imagine) is pretty inefficient:

```
qry.Where( parent => parent.Children.Where( child => child.IntCol == n ).FirstOrDefault().IntCol == n )
```

How can I do something like the first comparison to null that won't be generating nested queries and so forth?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
qry.Where( parent => parent.Children.Any( child => child.IntCol == n ));
```

`Any` in Linq translates to `exists` in sql.

If I understood Your queries correctly, this is what You need.

Comment: Well, the SQL and the execution plan look so similar it's difficult for me to determine if it's better.  This version does eliminate a cross apply, which seems good.

Comment: @dudeNumber4: It would be better if you wrote SQL query to translate to EF.